# OrientDB failover system

Tags: orientdb, failover

We are using OrientDB in our project, but sometimes we are getting deadlock inside of database. We want to make our system failover. 
Our idea is:

1. have two instances of OrientDB
2. all requests should be treated by first instance
3. when we get deadlock in database first instance should be killed and restarted
4. during restart all requests should be treated by second instance

After reading of documentation I need answers on next questions:

1. Can we have several instances of OrientDB running on one machine and working with the same database or we need to have duplication of database?
2. How can we restart instance of OrientDB after we get deadlock?
3. What is correct way to set "Replica" role to OrientDB instance? I tried to set

> "servers": {
>       "node1472377414807": "master",
>       "node1472377414808": "replica"
>     }

in default-distributed-db-config, but it seems both nodes are still masters

Comment: Could you please provide the thread-dump when you think the server is dead-locked?

Comment: Not sure on the replication question, but my java application that embeds OrientDB 2.2.2 sometimes hits what seems to be an OrientDB deadlock bug as well. Definitely submit the thread dump to them if you can. I can't submit a thread-dump, but will attempt to create a reproducer when I get time. In my case the deadlock seems to occur if some kind of read happens while I am dropping classes containing large amounts of binary data.